# Parse int and char into two separate values

Tags: c, string, parsing, char, int

I'm having the issues of trying to separate 1s or 2d into int 1 and  char 's' and then storing them as separate values.  How would I go about doing this.  I know I can't do it with `strtok` since there are no delimiters.

Comment: You might want to look at e.g. [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: I used the strtol and it gives me the int but how do I get the char too? is that saved in the pointer?

Comment: `sscanf(str, "%d%c", &ivar, &cvar);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strtol`. For example,

```
char *endptr;
val = strtol(input_str, &endptr, 10;
next_char = *endptr;
```

As discussed in the manpage, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html, the second parameter is a pointer to a char pointer and after the conversion, the char pointer points to the following character.

Answer (score 1):

You can access each char from the string by index. To convert char to int (not by ascii value, '1' to 1) you just do the following:

```
int a = c[0]-'0';
```

and for the char:

```
char b = c[1];
```

Comment: what if the string is stored in a pointer?

Comment: what do you mean? the variable I used for the string (c) should be a char array or a char* pointing to a string. it would work in both cases.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Then I know whats going on now.  Thank you!